# Converting a boolean array into a string using c#

Tags: c#

I have an array that looks something like:

```
status[0] = true
status[1] = true
status[2] = false
status[3] = true
```

In reality it's larger but still less than 20. I need to convert this into "ABD". Where each true represents an ordered letter in the alphabet. Can anyone think of an easy really efficient way to do this?

Comment: I'm afraid you'll need to flesh out your question a bit better. What value (true or false) become what letter?

Comment: @Jonathan I would assume 0 = 'A', 1 = 'B', ... but it would be nice for Beth to clarify

Comment: Pretty sure she means that the each index of the array is associated with the same index in the alpha bet. In her sample, 'true, true, false, true' = "ABD".

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear. Yes 0=A, 1=B etc. thanks

Comment: @Beth: If 0=A & 1=B, then what does "D" equal? I read your question the same way @Jon did.

Comment: @Everyone who doesn't understand: 0 = "A", 1 = "B", and 25 = "Z". All it is is "assigning" a letter to a number, in order, from 0 to 25.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string input = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

string result = new String(input.ToCharArray()
                      .Take(status.Length)
                      .Where((c, i) => status[i]).ToArray());
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I just had to point out how ugly that seems to me. :-) And I would love to see some comparisons of performance.

Comment: @svick added Take(length) for that.

Comment: @Beth it should be `status.Length`. Fixed now :D

Answer (score 7):

My napkin says this might work...

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for(int i = 0; i < status.Length; i++)
{
   if(status[i])
   {
       sb.Append((char)('A' + i));
   }
}

string result = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: As far as I can tell, this won't work. I get 656668. The reason is that you are not incrementing the value you cast to a `char` prior to casting it. You need to do something like `sb.Append( (char) ( i + 'A' ) );`

Comment: @svick - That's better. +1. Good job.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Linq:

```
var status = new bool[] { true, true, false, true };

// alternative 1
var statusString = string.Concat(
    status.Select((val, index) => val ? (char?)('A' + index) : null)
          .Where(x => x != null));

// alternative 2
var statusString2 = string.Concat( 
    status.Select((val, index) => val ? (object)(char)('A' + index) : ""));

// alternative 3 (same as one, no boxing)
var statusString3 = string.Concat(
    status.Select((val, index) => val ? (char)('A' + index) : ' ')
          .Where(x => x != ' '));


// alternative 4 (no Linq, probably faster)
var statusString4 = new StringBuilder(status.Length);
for (int i = 0; i < status.Length; i++)
{
    if (status[i])
        statusString4.Append((char)('A' + i));
}
```

Comment: I think this is the best answer so far. +1

Comment: +1 Since this answer shows some LINQ methods, What about using Zip (they finally added this in .NET 4?) and Where over the input and enumeration of 'A'..'Z'?

Answer (score 2):

```
String[] alphabet = new String[]  {"A", "B", ... "Z"};
String result = "";

for (int i = 0; i < status.Length; i++)
{
    if (status[i] == true) result += alphabet[i];
}
```

Basically, you can create an array of the letters of the alphabet and match the `true` values of your `status` array to the corresponding letter.

Comment: Since the letters are sequential, there is no need for the `Alphabet` array.

Comment: `if (foo == true)`!!  5 points from Gryffindor!  (no need for `== true`)

Comment: @Jonathan: Very true. For simplicity, I created the alphabet array. If the letters ever need to change, it's easy to modify the array.

Comment: @Daniel: After many, many years of programming, I personally prefer the `== true`.

Comment: @Jonathan Wood - After many, many years of programming I hate `==true` because it eventually morphs to `!=true` or `!=false`. Obviously personal preference.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class like this:

```
class Bool2CharArrayConverter
{

    public static string ConvertArray(bool[] Input)
    {
        int asc = 65;
        StringBuilder response = StringBuilder();
        foreach (bool val in Input)
        {
            if (val)
            {
                response.Append( Convert.ToChar(asc));
            }
            asc++;
        }
        return response.ToString();
    }
}
```

which can be invoked like this:

```
     bool[] status = new bool[]{true,true,false,true};
     string output = Bool2CharArrayConverter.ConvertArray(status);
     Console.WriteLine(output); //output = ABD
```